# How to skip actions when a specific element is clicked more the once?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

When the clicked_line element is clicked, it can have red or blue class(I did it with game_status), but when a specific element is clicked more than once it must be unchanged.

I don't know how to use e.target.classList.length or e.target.classList.contains('blue') (and e.target.classList.contains('red')) to do this.

I think classList is like a pointer.

```
<div class="row horizontal_lines_container">
    <!-- Elements that forms horizontal lines  -->
    <div class="horizontal_line"></div>
    <div class="horizontal_line"></div>
    <div class="horizontal_line"></div>
    <div class="horizontal_line"></div>
    <div class="horizontal_line"></div>
    <div class="horizontal_line"></div>
    <div class="horizontal_line"></div>
</div>
```

```
function handleClicklEvent(e) {
    const clicked_line = e.target
    console.log("length:", clicked_line.classList.length)
    console.log("Has red class?", clicked_line.classList.contains('red'))
    console.log("Has blue class?", clicked_line.classList.contains('blue'))
    //if(what must be here?) {
        // do these things if clicked_line only clicked once.
        clicked_line.classList.add(game_status);
        toggle_game_status(); // toggle between red and blue
        player_turn.innerHTML = game_status; 
    //}   
}

document
    .querySelectorAll('.horizontal_line, .vertical_line')
    .forEach(line => {
        line.addEventListener('click', handleClicklEvent)
})
```

Comment: So when you click once, you want to change the color (blue or red) and when you double click the color should be removed?

Comment: No, double click isn't care, and the second click doesn't need any action.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. How many clickable elements are there and what should happen when you click them? Could you clarify your question and maybe provide more code like the HTML?

Comment: Its like the "Dots and Boxes" game, there are many clickable elements, when click them for the first time their color must be changed and for more than once, their color no need to change.